# GlobalUsings.g.cs cannot be found MAUI after .NET 8 upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-8.0

Tried to upgrade to .NET 8 and I am getting this error now:

> Error CS2001
> Source file 'C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Solution\project\obj\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\project.GlobalUsings.g.cs' could not be found.

However when I go to this location, the `project.GlobalUsings.g.cs` is there just fine and contains:

```
// <auto-generated/>
global using global::Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Accessibility;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Authentication;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Devices;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Dispatching;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Hosting;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Media;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Networking;
global using global::Microsoft.Maui.Storage;
global using global::System;
global using global::System.Collections.Generic;
global using global::System.IO;
global using global::System.Linq;
global using global::System.Net.Http;
global using global::System.Threading;
global using global::System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Tried clean, clean & rebuild, manually close VS and delete bin&obj and clean and rebuild. The error persists.

I changed:

```
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

to

```
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

I was expecting it to compile with .NET 8, however it will not build.

Project file is as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
    <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Project</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>Application</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.domain.id</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>B043F5CF-029D-41D9-BCEE-945AD3617577</ApplicationIdGuid>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.8</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
    
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>True</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows' and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>true</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
    <PackageCertificateThumbprint>A24C3CE55E9658F0EDDE627BF879C2B2CA8BB633</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows' and '$(RuntimeIdentifierOverride)' != ''">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>$(RuntimeIdentifierOverride)</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\AppIcon\*" />
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Splash\*" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <MauiImage Remove="Resources\Splash\splash.scale-100.png" />
  <MauiImage Remove="Resources\Splash\splash.scale-125.png" />
  <MauiImage Remove="Resources\Splash\splash.scale-150.png" />
  <MauiImage Remove="Resources\Splash\splash.scale-200.png" />
  <MauiImage Remove="Resources\Splash\splash.scale-400.png" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="logo256.scale-100.png" />
  <None Remove="logo256.scale-200.png" />
  <None Remove="logo256.scale-400.png" />
  <None Remove="logo256.targetsize-256.png" />
  <None Remove="gdp_pc.json" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Splash\bvisplash.scale-400.png" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="logo256.scale-100.png" />
  <Content Include="logo256.scale-200.png" />
  <Content Include="logo256.scale-400.png" />
  <Content Include="logo256.targetsize-256.png" />
  <Content Include="Resources\Splash\splash.scale-100.png" />
  <Content Include="Resources\Splash\plash.scale-125.png" />
  <Content Include="Resources\Splash\splash.scale-150.png" />
  <Content Include="Resources\Splash\splash.scale-200.png" />
  <Content Include="Resources\Splash\plash.scale-400.png" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="gdp_pc.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.6.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="PInvoke.User32" Version="0.7.124" />
  <PackageReference Include="UraniumUI.Icons.MaterialIcons" Version="2.2.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="UraniumUI.Material" Version="2.2.5" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Services\Project.Services.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Pages\AccountPaymentsHistoryPage.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>AccountPaymentsHistoryPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="Pages\MarketingContactsPage.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>MarketingContactsPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="Pages\LatestAccountsPage.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>LatestAccountsPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="Pages\DashboardPage.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>DashboardPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="Pages\AccountsPage.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>AccountsPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="Pages\NewAdminFormPage.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>NewAdminFormPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="Pages\RatesPage.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>RatesPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <MauiXaml Update="Pages\AccountPaymentsHistoryPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Pages\AdminsManager.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Pages\MarketingContactsPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Pages\LatestAccountsPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Pages\DashboardPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Pages\NewAdminFormPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Pages\RatesPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Pages\LoginPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="ExtensionMethods\" />
  <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
  <Folder Include="Resources\AppIcon\" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="rmdir /s /q &quot;$(ProjectDir)bin&quot;&#xA;rmdir /s /q &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj&quot;" />
</Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I need to see your project file, the whole thing

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have edited the post to include the project file

Comment: Is your project windows only?

Comment: 1) What IDE are you using? 2) Try building project with `dotnet build` 3) If you are using VS - try deleting bin and obj folders, restarting IDE and building again, also try upgrading VS to the latest version

Comment: Your project file looks ok, you might want to clean up the bin and obj and restore the NuGet packages once, before clean and rebuilding.

Comment: Yes its windows only. Yes its Visual studio, I have done all differnet manner of Clean, Rebuild, Delete bin&obj, restart, rebuild, update.
I did see this in the "output" tab on trying to rebuild :
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2382,5): warning MSB3101: Could not write state file "obj\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\Project.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache".